# Merge two lists of dicts in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas

I have two lists of dicts: one which has monthly data, and another which has quarterly data as follows:

```
monthly = [
{
    "name": "Boston",
    "month": "2015-May",  
    "total_monthly": 2
}, 
{
    "name": "Boston",
    "month": "2015-June",  
    "total_monthly": 8
}, 
{
    "name": "Chicago",
    "month": "2015-May",  
    "total_monthly": 10
},
{
    "name": "Chicago",
    "month": "2015-June",  
    "total_monthly": 13
}
]

quarterly =[
{
    "name": "Boston",
    "quarter": "2015-Q1",  
    "total_quarterly": 23
}, 
{
    "name": "Boston",
    "quarter": "2015-Q2",  
    "total_quarterly": 24
}, 
{
    "name": "Chicago",
    "quarter": "2015-Q1",  
    "total_quarterly": 40
},
{
    "name": "Chicago",
    "quarter": "2015-Q2",  
    "total_quarterly": 32
}
]
```

Conventionally, I can iterate through the lists and merge them based on common names. However, how can I achieve the merged data as follows using Pandas?

```
merged = [
{
  "name": "Boston",
  "trend_monthly" : [
    {
      "month": "2015-May",  
      "total_monthly": 2
    }, 
    {
      "month": "2015-June",  
      "total_monthly": 8
    },
  ],  
  "trend_quarterly" : [
    {
      "quarter": "2015-Q1",  
      "total_quarterly": 23
    }, 
    {
      "quarter": "2015-Q2",  
      "total_quarterly": 24
    },
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Chicago",
  "trend_monthly" : [
    {
      "month": "2015-May",  
      "total_monthly": 10
    }, 
    {
      "month": "2015-June",  
      "total_monthly": 13
    },
  ],  
  "trend_quarterly" : [
    {
      "quarter": "2015-Q1",  
      "total_quarterly": 40
    }, 
    {
      "quarter": "2015-Q2",  
      "total_quarterly": 32
    },
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "trend_quarterly" list on the bottom of the merged dict be: "trend_quarterly" : [
    {
      "quarter": "2015-Q1",  
      "total_quarterly": 40
    }, 
    {
      "quarter": "2015-Q2",  
      "total_quarterly": 32
    },
  ] ?

Comment: @hhbilly..yes..typo on my part..corrected now..

Comment: Do you want to get a list of dicts at the end or a pandas DF?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_monthly = pd.DataFrame(monthly)
df_quarterly = pd.DataFrame(quarterly)

df = pd.concat([df_monthly, df_quarterly])

# This part does not group correctly, please edit for your needs
result = []
dict_monthly = dict(list(df[df.month.notnull()][['name',
                                                  'month',
                                                  'total_monthly']
                                                ].groupby(by='name')))

dict_quarterly = dict(list(df[df.quarter.notnull()][['name',
                                                  'quarter',
                                                  'total_quarterly']
                                                ].groupby(by='name')))
result.append(dict_monthly)
result.append(dict_quarterly)
```